# Removing numbers from bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, numbering

I'm trying to remove the numbering from my bibliography (I'm supposed to cite by last name & year). I've tried adding

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\makeatother
```

to my preamble, as I have seen suggested elsewhere, but it doesn't seem to work for me. No matter what I put in the `{}`, there is no change in my output. I am using a `thebibliography` environment, and \bibitem{key}... to make my bibliography entries.

My document class is:
`\documentclass[preprint,showpacs,preprintnumbers,tightenlines,titlepage,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4-1}`

Comment: Your last sentence is a bit unclear. Are you saying that you are building the bibliography "by hand", using instructions such as `\begin{thebibliography}{nn}`, `\bibitem[...]{...}...`, and `\end{thebibliography}`? Which document class do you use? Do you load any citation management packages such as `cite` or `natbib`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You will have to give us some minimal but compilable code which reproduces your problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I am manually editing the bibliography. I updated my post to include the document class. I haven't loaded any citation packages. Should I?

Comment: Don't you put the author-year label in the optional argument to `\bibitem` in this case? E.g. `\bibitem[Butterworth 2004]{butter2004} Butterworth, Angelina (2004), 'The Life of the Coconut Shrew'...`? [Note: I've never in my life coded a bibliography in TeX by hand.]

Comment: @cfr Are you saying that I should be putting in the optional argument to get the intended output? If you're just generally asking, no, I don't usually put that in. I have just been writing `\bibitem{butter2004} Butterworth, .....`

Comment: Well, that would give you the intended output. Whether that is how it is normally done, I'm not sure.